# Execption: Cannot create a DataRelation if Parent or Child Columns are not in a DataSet

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i tried to create relashionship between two tables,
(access)

my code:

```
    Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet("DataSet")
    DataSet1.Tables.Add(getTable(TableName, con)) 'Returns DataTable
    Dim DataRelation1 As DataRelation = New DataRelation(TableName, Column1, Column2, True) ' Execption Here !!!
    DataRelation1.Nested = True
    DataSet1.Relations.Add(obj_DataRelation)
```

Exception:

```
Cannot create a DataRelation if Parent or Child Columns are not in a DataSet.
```

I missed something?( yes but what :/ )(Example C# / VB.net is the best answer)

Answer (score 0):

A relation must be between two tables. you need to have a DataSet with at least 2 Tables to set up a DataRelation.

Comment: You mean : two Columns Column2 = Column of table 2 (DataColumn not string) 1 of PrimaryTable and the second column of ForeignTable but the relation is between columns of two different tables.

Comment: Usually a relation is set up between the primary key column in the first table and the matching foreign key column in the other table. See http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/

Answer (score 0):

The columns you're passing in, `Column1` and `Column2`, either belong to different data sets or simply aren't both in the same data set.

Comment: they in the same database , the dataset contains : Tables1 + Table2 ,
and Column1 of Table1 ,Column2 of Table2 and still execption.

Comment: @user2987791, something is missing because that can't be true. That's the only way this exception is thrown. Make sure that `Column1` and `Column2` are **exactly** what you *think* they are.